# Sessions in Codeigniter ( Display active users)

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I have ci_sessions table and when i run this query it gives m 0 count for active users but i have loged in with 2 different acount with different browsers my query is that i run in phpmyadmin

```
SELECT COUNT(`session_id`) AS `active_user_count` 
FROM `ci_session` 
WHERE `last_activity` >= DATE_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, INTERVAL 2 MINUTE) 
    AND `user_data` 
LIKE '%s:9:"logged_in";b:1;%'
```

i want to calculate all active users

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT COUNT(`session_id`) AS `active_user_count` 
FROM `ci_session` 
WHERE `last_activity` >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 MINUTE)) 
    AND `user_data` 
LIKE '%s:9:"logged_in";b:1;%'
```